# Spring: How to treat prototyped beans in a spring container, singleton scoped for a certain subpart of the object graph?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

I think this is a trivial problem, yet I couldn't find any discussions about it.
 I have `DeeplyNestedObject` whose object graph should be autowired through the injection of `Dependency`. Inside this object graph `Dependency` should be singleton scoped.

```
 class DeeplyNestedObject {
     Dependency dependency;//should be same instance as in SomeOtherObject
     SomeOtherObject someOtherObject;

     @Autowired
     public DeeplyNestedObject(Dependency dependency,
                               SomeOtherObject someOtherObject){
          this.dependency = dependency; 
          this.someOtherObject = someOtherObject;
     }

 }

 //this is just some other class nested inside DeeplyNestedObject's object graph
 class SomeOtherObject{
     Dependency dependency;//should be same instance as in DeeplyNestedObject

     @Autowired
     public DeeplyNestedObject(Dependency dependency){
          this.dependency = dependency; 
     }

 }
```

Since I only need `Dependency` to autowire *SomeOtherObject* and thus  *DeeplyNestedObject*, this bean configuration should be sufficient:

```
@Bean
Dependency dependency(){
     return new Dependency();
 }
```

I have three requirements though

1. The `DeeplyNestedObject` shall be prototyped, so I want a new instance of this object graph every time I autowire it somewhere
2. A `Dependency` should be treated as a singleton **within** this object graph,
3. Each *DeeplyNestedObject* should have its own instance of *Dependency*

I can't solve the following problem:

- If I scope *Dependency* as prototype, I will always get a new *Dependency* instance, breaching constraint 2 (`Dependency` in *DeeplyNestedObject* and *SomeOtherObject* would be different)
- If I scope *Dependency* as a Singleton, then I'll violate constraint 3 (each `DeeplyNestedObject` and its object graphs would share the same `Dependency` object)

Basically what I *think* I need is to introduce another IoC container for *DeeplyNestedObject* into which I can inject *Dependency* and then provide it as a Singleton for the `DeeplyNestedObject` graph. However, I didn't see any solution like this so far.

Answer (score 2):

> If I scope Dependency as prototype, I will always get a new instance,
>   breaching constraint 2

I don't think.
Spring creates a new instance for a prototype scoped bean **only as an injection or a bean loading is requested**.
So if you don't perform other bean loading/injection of `Dependency` in `DeeplyNestedObject` once the `DeeplyNestedObject` bean was added in the bean container, you would have a distinct `Dependency` instance by `DeeplyNestedObject` instance.

Comment: But this is only the case when I pass `Dependency` to the constructor of `DeeplyNestedObject`, so I would work with constructor injection and I'd need to supply all the other constructor args as well. Imagine I want Spring to wire up the _DeeplyNestedObject_ **entirely** itself. In this case only the @Bean Dependency-definition would exist in the configuration. How would it work then?

Comment: " Imagine I want Spring to wire up the DeeplyNestedObject entirely itself." Sorry I am not sure to understand. You have to define injection on constructor, field or setter to indicate to Spring that you want to wire up something.  How Spring could do it without indicators ? Don't hesitate to edit your post if you have a very specific example that makes sense.

Comment: I edited my OP and changed the title. I hope the problem became clearer?

Comment: I will look at that in the next days :) I would say you :)